# C array of unions not being modified

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, unions

I am having a problem with the following code. It is supposed to be a simple `.obj` loader that stores the data in three different arrays. The arrays are being passed into the function, but they are not modified. The line `*out_vertices[index] = gl_vector3_make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` also throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` every time I use the function, even if I pre-allocate the arrays that I pass in and remove all of the related allocation code in the function itself.

ObjectIO.h

```
#ifndef ObjectIO_h
#define ObjectIO_h

union _vector2 {
    struct {float x, y;};
    struct {float s, t;};
    float v[2];
};
typedef union _vector2 gl_vector2;

extern inline gl_vector2 gl_vector2_make(float x, float y);

union _vector3 {
    struct {float x, y, z;};
    struct {float s, t, p;};
    struct {float r, g, b;};
    float v[3];
};
typedef union _vector3 gl_vector3;

extern inline gl_vector3 gl_vector3_make(float x, float y, float z);

union _vector4 {
    struct {float x, y, z, w;};
    struct {float s, t, p, q;};
    struct {float r, g, b, a;};
    float v[4];
};
typedef union _vector4 gl_vector4;

extern inline gl_vector4 gl_vector4_make(float x, float y, float z, float w);

extern inline int loadOBJ(const char *path, gl_vector3 **out_vertices, gl_vector2 **out_uvs, gl_vector3 **out_normals);

#endif
```

ObjectIO.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ObjectIO.h"

extern inline gl_vector2 gl_vector2_make(float x, float y) {
    gl_vector2 vector;

    vector.x = x;
    vector.y = y;

    return vector;
}

extern inline gl_vector3 gl_vector3_make(float x, float y, float z) {
    gl_vector3 vector;

    vector.x = x;
    vector.y = y;
    vector.z = z;

    return vector;
}

extern inline gl_vector4 gl_vector4_make(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
    gl_vector4 vector;

    vector.x = x;
    vector.y = y;
    vector.z = z;
    vector.w = w;

    return vector;
}

extern inline char** splitstring(char *inputstring, char *separator, size_t *lines) {
    char **res = NULL;
    char * p = strtok(inputstring, separator);
    int n_spaces = 0, i;

    while (p) {
        n_spaces ++;
        res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL)
            exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

        res[n_spaces - 1] = p;

        p = strtok (NULL, separator);
    }

    res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces + 1));
    res[n_spaces] = '\0';

    /* print the result */

    for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces); i ++) printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, res[i]);

    /* free the memory allocated */

    *lines = (n_spaces - 1);
    free(res);

    return res;
}

extern inline int loadOBJ(const char *path, gl_vector3 **out_vertices, gl_vector2 **out_uvs, gl_vector3 **out_normals) {
    printf("Loading OBJ file %s...\n", path);
    long filesize;
    char *file_c;
    char *linesep;
    char **filecontents;
    size_t filecontentsize, result, lines, index, faces;
    float *normals = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
    float *uvs = malloc(sizeof(float) * 2);
    float *vertices = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File %s cannot be opened.\n", path);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    filecontentsize = sizeof(char) * filesize;
    file_c = malloc(filecontentsize);
    result = fread(file_c, 1, filesize, file);

    linesep = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    linesep[0] = '\n';
    lines = 0;
    index = 0;
    faces = 0;
    filecontents = splitstring(file_c, linesep, &lines);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (index < lines) {
        if (filecontents[index][0] == 'v') {
            if (filecontents[index][1] == 'n') {
                normals = realloc(normals, (sizeof(float) * 3));

                fscanf(file, "vn %f %f %f\n", &normals[(index * 3) + 0], &normals[(index * 3) + 1], &normals[(index * 3) + 2]);
            }
            else {
                if (filecontents[index][1] == 't') {
                    uvs = realloc(uvs, (sizeof(float) * 2));
                    fscanf(file, "vt %f %f\n", &uvs[(index * 3) + 0], &uvs[(index * 3) + 1]);
                }
                else {
                    vertices = realloc(vertices, (sizeof(float) * 3));
                    fscanf(file, "v %f %f %f\n", &vertices[(index * 3) + 0], &vertices[(index * 3) + 1], &vertices[(index * 3) + 2]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (filecontents[index][0] == 'f') {
            faces ++;
        }

        index ++;
    }

    *out_vertices = malloc(sizeof(gl_vector3) * faces * 3);
    *out_uvs = malloc(sizeof(gl_vector2) * faces * 2);
    *out_normals = malloc(sizeof(gl_vector3) * faces * 3);

    index = 0;
    while (index <= lines) {
        *out_normals[index] = gl_vector3_make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        *out_uvs[index] = gl_vector2_make(0.0, 0.0);
        *out_vertices[index] = gl_vector3_make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        printf("%lu\n", index);
        index ++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 1;
}
```

The function is called here:

```
gl_vector3 *normals;
gl_vector2 *uvs;
gl_vector3 *vertices;

loadOBJ("/Users/justin/Downloads/OpenGL-tutorial_v0010_21/tutorial16_shadowmaps/room.obj", &vertices, &uvs, &normals);
printf("%f, %f, %f\n", vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y, vertices[0].z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a union of 2, 3, or 4 identical anonymous structs, which is strange, but ok, sure. Your functions gl_vector2_make, gl_vector3_make, and gl_vector4_make are not, as I first misread, returning pointers, so that's ok too. The way you use realloc() is severely inefficient, but sure, go ahead. However, your function `splitstring()` allocates storage, fills it with points into the string data you want to process, then it *frees* the allocated storage before returning a pointer to it. That's a serious bug. In your function `loadOBJ()`, your variables named `normals`, `uvs`, and `vertices` are all allocated to fixed sizes, but even though you `realloc()` them repeatedly, you never *grow* any of them. You always allocate the same size. And then you index into them based off the size you wanted to allocate, which is, again, a major bug. Further, in `loadOBJ()`, you read the entire file into allocated memory, pass it to `splitstring()` which breaks it into a near array of strings, line by line, and then instead of actually *using* that, you rewind the file and use `fscanf()` to read the whole file in again, a line at a time. Why not use `sscanf()` on each of the array of strings returned by `splitstring()`?

Comment: Well, the union thing is just for my benefit. When I am using a `gl_vector4` to store colors, for example, using the `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a` helps me to remember the exact purpose.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. What about the functions that are returning pointers to local variables?

Comment: Ah. You're not returning *pointers* to local variables, you're returning the values, and I clearly misread. Hmm.

Comment: Completely rewrote answer. Read it again.